# Creating an rdlc report with multiple tables (one-to-many relationship)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, report, rdlc

So, I'm new to rdlc (and reporting in general actually). I have a table that has a one-to-many relationship with another table, and I'm trying to represent them in an rdlc report as multiple tables *for each item*.

**Note: The tables are originally created using Entity Framework code-first**.

Here are the two tables *(and the parent one)*:

[image: Quotation model]

Now, normally if I only have the `[Quotation]` and some `[QuotationItem]`s, I'd just add the info from the `[Quotation]` on the top of the report, and the info from each `[QuotationItem]` would be represented in a row inside a table (Tablix).

**The problem is**: Each `[QuotationItem]` also *has many* of `[QuotationItemQuantity]` (currently three), and they need to be represented too.

So, my report should look something like this:

[image: Report]

But I'm stuck on how to display multiple tables (or a list and tables) for each item (QuotationItem). I tried nested tables and tables inside a list, but this doesn't seem to be allowed (I get a *"Detail members can only contain static inner members"* error).

I read about sub-reports and I think this might be the way to go, but I'm not sure how to use sub-reports in this case, or if this is actually the right approach.

Note: As mentioned above, each `QuotationItem` currently has 3 quantities, but that might be changed in the future, so would be great if the columns can be dynamic, however, this isn't a requirement at this point.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

Well, I was hoping (and still do) to get a more elegant solution *instead of this ugly one* (which I had to use for now) but it does what it's supposed to anyway.

I'm posting it as it might help someone with a similar problem. Here's what I did:

### Preparing the data:

- Created a dummy DataSet using the VS designer, and added one DataTable to it.
- Added all the *required* columns from both tables into this DataTable.
- Added the DataSet as the data source for the report.
- In order to pass the actual data, I would fill a DataTable *with the same structure as the designed one* and then pass it to the report using something like the following:

  ```
  private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      rptViewerMain.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "MyProjectName.QuotationReport.rdlc";
      rptViewerMain.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;

      if (QuotationInfo !=null && QuotationItems != null)
      {
          SetupReport();
      }

      this.rptViewerMain.RefreshReport();
  }

  private void SetupReport()
  {
      var param1 = new ReportParameter("MyFirstParameter", SomeValue);
      var param2 = new ReportParameter("MySecondParameter", SomeOtherValue);
      // etc

      // Pass Parameters
      rptViewerMain.LocalReport.SetParameters(new[] { param1, param2, "etc" });

      // Prepare the DataTable and add the values to it
      DataTable dt = new MyDummyDataset.MyDesignedDataTable().Clone();

      foreach (var qItem in QuotationItems)
      {
          dt.Rows.Add(qItem.ItemNumber, qItem.ItemDescription, "and",
                      "so", "many", "more", "values");
      }

      // Pass the DataTable to the report as the data source replacing the dummy DataSet
      rptViewerMain.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("MyDummyDataset", dt));
  }
  ```

### Designing the report:

- Created only one table (Tablix) in the RDLC report and used the cell borders to make it look like 3 tables *by removing the borders of the unwanted cells between the "tables"*:
  [image]
- Added the fields from the dummy DataSet to the corresponding cells in the first table (the quantities info) and above the table (the quotation item info).
- For the second and third "tables", simply used expressions to do the calculations based on the values from the first table.

Note: Some fields/variables names were changed in both the question and the answer, but the idea stays the same.